# Pandas: как 19 колонок разбить на три части?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В датафрейме 19 колонок имеют в каждой ячейки по 3 значения разделенные \n. Эти значения нужно разделить по трем доп колонкам: 'Абс.число', 'Грубый', 'Уд.вес,%'. И так чтобы у каждой новой колонки появилась приписка наименования старой колонки, например, 'Абс.число_0-4', 'Грубый_0-4', 'Уд.вес,%_0-4'. Старые колонки нужно удалить.

Я попробовала сделать так:

```
new_data = {}

for key, value in data.items():

    column_values = value.str.split('\n', expand=True)
    
    if len(column_values) >= 3:
        new_data[key] = {
            'Абс.число': column_values[0],
            'Грубый': column_values[1],
            'Уд.вес,%': column_values[2]
        }
```

Код не сработал. Там ещё проблема что помимо 19 колонок, есть 3 колонки, которые имеют только одно значение в ячейке.

В целом можно каждую по отдельности колонку разбить на три новые и переименовать, но получается большой и не красивый код. Не понимаю как код более лаконично и красиво написать и чтобы ещё и время сохранить(

[image: Датафрейм]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Всегда предоставляйте пример исходных данных в своем вопросе!**

Предположим, у вас есть таблица df:

```
  name       Всего            0-4   5-9
0  one     1\n2\n3     11\n22\n33   111
1  two  1a\n2a\n3a  11a\n22a\n33a  111a
```

к сожалению, я сомневаюсь, что через векторизацию (apply) можно будет создать эффективный код для решения вашей проблемы - возникнет путаница с индексами и скорость работы будет низкой на больших таблицах. поэтому предлагаю сделать как-нибудь так:

```
cols_to_apply = df.columns[1:-1].to_list() # выбираете  столбцы для обработки, либо
                                           # задавайте из вручную

for x in cols_to_apply:
    _df = df[x].str.split("\n", expand=True)
    _df = _df.rename(columns={i:f"{i}_{x}" for i in _df.columns})
    df = pd.concat([df, _df], axis=1).drop(columns=[x])
```

получаете df:

```
  name   5-9 0_Всего 1_Всего 2_Всего 0_0-4 1_0-4 2_0-4
0  one   111       1       2       3    11    22    33
1  two  111a      1a      2a      3a   11a   22a   33a
```

разумеется, порядок столбцов поменяется.

Answer (score 1):

Транспонируем фрейм, применяем лямбду к строкам (в лямбде преобразуем все в текст и распиливаем в списки). Потом размножаем строки "взрывом" и транспонируем обратно. Затем формируем названия колонок - каждые три подряд идущие одинаковые названия дополняем префиксами.
Преимущества решения:

- не нужно перечислять колонки для распиливания;
- порядок следования столбцов не нарушается.

Недостатки:

- все содержимое фрейма преобразуется в текст;
- чувствительность к качеству исходных данных в части наличия и количества `\n`.

```
prefixes = ['Абс.число_', 'Грубый_', 'Уд.вес,%_']
df = pd.DataFrame({'0-1': ['125\n111\n12', '125\n111\n12', '125\n111\n12'], 'Между': [123, 'aaa', None], '0-2': ['126\n111\n12', '125\n111\n12', '125\n111\n12'], 'Другая': [45, 15, 20]})
df = df.T.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split('\n'), axis=1)
df = df.explode(list(df.columns)).T
# оформление названия колонок
cols = list(df.columns)
for i in range(len(cols) - 2):
    if len(set(cols[i:i + 3])) == 1:
        cols[i:i + 3] = (prefixes[x] + cols[i + x] for x in range(3))
        i += 2
df.columns = cols
print(df)
```

```
  Абс.число_0-1 Грубый_0-1 Уд.вес,%_0-1 Между Абс.число_0-2 Грубый_0-2 Уд.вес,%_0-2 Другая
0           125        111           12   123           126        111           12     45
1           125        111           12   aaa           125        111           12     15
2           125        111           12  None           125        111           12     20
```